# Run Python code line by line to debug function inside a class

Tags: python, function, class, debugging

Normally, to debug a function outside a class I will assign all of its parameters then run & check the function code line by line. (Yes, I know this might not be a professional way!). However, for a function inside a class, it gets error because of the `self`

For eg, whichever line I run inside this class, it will say:

```
 self.issue_date = issue_date          
 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-70-6d3e45750988>", line 1, in <module>
     self.issue_date = issue_date         
 
 NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So, how to run code inside a class line by line? Or how do you guys debug a function inside a class?

Below is an eg of my class.

```
class fixed_bond:
    def __init__(self, issue_date, settlement_date, first_coupon_date, maturity_date, face_value, df1, df2, coupon_rate, roll, coupon_frequency, day_count_convention):
        ##################################################################################
        #Setting up inital attributes
        ##################################################################################
        self.issue_date = issue_date             
        self.settlement_date = settlement_date    
        self.first_coupon_date = first_coupon_date
        self.maturity_date = maturity_date       
        self.face_value = face_value             
        self.coupon_rate = coupon_rate      

        if self.roll =='Following':
           for i in range(self.number_of_periods):     
               while cash_flow_dates[i].weekday() < 5:
                   cash_flow_dates[i]=cash_flow_dates[i] + relativedelta(days = 1)   
        .......
        (end of class eg)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: How are you instantiating the class? ```self``` is used to represent the instance. If you call it outside the class, python won't recognise it

Comment: @Sujay I just manually assign all parameters. For eg, I run `issue_date = df[x]`,    `first_coupon_date = df[y]`. What should I do if I want to run & check each line of the class function?

Comment: @quamrana yes, I editted

Comment: Ok, so I would debug by setting a break point. How do you manage to get to the line in question?

Comment: I would suggest [using pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to step through your code.